# Bash terminal command worries

Tags: python, bash, macos

I have recently become the owner of a MacBook.
Due to this and my programming I have been using the terminal a lot.
I was bored so decided to mash my keyboard and ended up with an input of

```
agr'l
```

This was fine until it brought about the start of the line being > and it waiting for an input. Also at the beginning and the end of the line it has squared brackets as if they are bing held together

Any help that could be given on what this is would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: I should also add that this is just from the default bash terminal

Comment: I think it's just looking for the closing single quote. Try entering that.

Comment: What exactly is your question and can you paste the output you got and what specifically you want to know about it?

Comment: Closing the single quote and hitting enter will exit out of the >, just tested it. Also you can always use ctrl+c

Comment: This is just a question about *using your shell*, which is a general-purpose tool. StackOverflow's scope is explicitly limited to questions about software development and tools unique to that purpose.

Comment: Nothing about this is specific to macOS.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the context is programming, the thing itself is a programming language, the explanation has to do with the interactive use of that language, it's reasonably within the scope or at least, not an important hill of strict on-topicness to defend.

Answer (score 1):

In the common Bourne compatible Unix shells (*sh*, *ksh* (Korn shell), *bash*, and *zsh*, among others) the shell will allow continuation of lines which contain unmatched quotation marks or other delimiters (such has parentheses for blocking commands with a subshell or {curly;braces} for grouping statements together).  Also lines ending in a backslash \ character will be continued.

In these cases the shell will display your ***$PS2*** prompt string (the one you're using to seeing is ***$PS1*** ... "prompt string: primary" vs. the "prompt string: secondary."  There are a couple of other ***$PS_*** environment variable for prompting generated by a call to the *select* built-in and for the output lines from tracing execution of a shell script (using the *set -x* command, or the *-x* command line option to the shell).

Read the man pages and search on PS1 through PS4 to learn more about each one.

Comment: Eh? POSIX-compliant shells are not Bourne compatible. If you want to prove this, try `echo foo ^ cat` -- in original 1970s Bourne, as opposed to shells compliant with the (ksh-influenced) early-1990s POSIX sh standard, `^` is a pipe symbol, so this will print `foo`; on modern shells, it prints `foo ^ cat`. Which is to say: "Bourne Again" is clever wordplay, but *not* accurately descriptive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: please feel free to create your own page or answer for pedantry.  I clearly was referring to the "common" shells which are "Bourne" compatible to distinguish them from *csh* and the various exotic shells (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Exotic_shells) which one might encounter.  Please feel free to also find a modern version of Unix. Linux, or MacOS X which includes one of the ancient Bourne shells and tell us all about them (somewhere else).

Comment: To answer your question there -- Solaris shipped ancient Bourne well into the mid-2000s. (It's also available, and actively maintained, through the Heirloom project).

Comment: ...my request, to be clear, is that you use the phrase "POSIX-compliant" or "POSIX-superset" rather than "Bourne-compatible".

Comment: BTW, I'm not adding an answer principally because doing so would violate the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" guideline from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, which explicitly discourages answering off-topic questions.